# Query that detects the differences between yesterdays load and todays load but populates error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

We are converting an old legacy program and integrate it in SSIS. The old program outputs a file that shows the difference of the account to the end users who need to be notified of account changes. Here is the query I am trying to do to execute this but I am getting the error "The conversion of the varchar value '02393224650' overflowed an int column." Before you say "possible duplicate". None of the other post properly answer this question or are involving a query that implements logic in this manner.

```
      SELECT
      a.run_id,
      a.AccountNumber,
      a.AccountBranch,
      a.AccountName,
      a.AccountType,
      a.CostCenter,
      b.TransactionLimit,
      b.ClientName,
      b.DailyCumulativeLimit
    FROM 
      AEI_GFXAccounts a
      LEFT JOIN AEI_GFXAccountSTP as b
      ON 
        a.feed_id = b.feed_id and 
        a.run_id = b.run_id and a.GFXAccountsID = b.GFXAccountSTPID), 
yest AS (
  SELECT * FROM data WHERE run_id = (SELECT MAX(run_id)-1 FROM AEI_GFXAccounts)
),
toda AS (
  SELECT * FROM data WHERE run_id = (SELECT MAX(run_id) FROM AEI_GFXAccounts)
)

SELECT
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.AccountNumber, 0) <> COALESCE(toda.AccountNumber, 0) THEN yest.AccountNumber END as yest_AccountNumber,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.AccountNumber, 0) <> COALESCE(toda.AccountNumber, 0) THEN toda.AccountNumber END as toda_AccountNumber,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.AccountBranch, 0) <> COALESCE(toda.AccountBranch, 0) THEN yest.AccountBranch END as yest_AccountBranch,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.AccountBranch, 0) <> COALESCE(toda.AccountBranch, 0) THEN toda.AccountBranch END as toda_AccountBranch,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.AccountName, 'x')   <> COALESCE(toda.AccountName, 'x')   THEN yest.AccountName   END as yest_AccountName,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.AccountName, 'x')   <> COALESCE(toda.AccountName, 'x')   THEN toda.AccountName   END as toda_AccountName,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.AccountType, 'n/a')   <> COALESCE(toda.AccountType, 'n/a')   THEN yest.AccountType   END as yest_AccountType,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.AccountType, 'n/a')   <> COALESCE(toda.AccountType, 'n/a')   THEN toda.AccountType   END as toda_AccountType,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.CostCenter, 0)   <> COALESCE(toda.CostCenter, 0)   THEN yest.CostCenter   END as yest_CostCenter,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.CostCenter, 0)   <> COALESCE(toda.CostCenter, 0)   THEN toda.CostCenter  END as toda_CostCenter,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.TransactionLimit, 0)   <> COALESCE(toda.TransactionLimit, 0)   THEN yest.TransactionLimit   END as yest_TransactionLimit,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.TransactionLimit, 0)   <> COALESCE(toda.TransactionLimit, 0)   THEN toda.TransactionLimit  END as toda_TransactionLimit,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.ClientName, 'x')   <> COALESCE(toda.ClientName, 'x')   THEN yest.ClientName   END as yest_ClientName,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.ClientName, 'x')   <> COALESCE(toda.ClientName, 'x')   THEN toda.ClientName  END as toda_ClientName,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.DailyCumulativeLimit, 0)   <> COALESCE(toda.DailyCumulativeLimit, 0)   THEN yest.DailyCumulativeLimit   END as yest_DailyCumulativeLimit,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(yest.DailyCumulativeLimit, 0)   <> COALESCE(toda.DailyCumulativeLimit, 0)   THEN toda.DailyCumulativeLimit  END as toda_DailyCumulativeLimit

FROM
  toda LEFT JOIN yest ON toda.accountNumber = yest.AccountNumber

WHERE
  COALESCE(toda.AccountNumber,   0) <> COALESCE(yest.AccountNumber,   0) OR 
  COALESCE(toda.AccountBranch, 0) <> COALESCE(yest.AccountBranch, 0) OR      
  COALESCE(toda.AccountName,   'x') <> COALESCE(yest.AccountName,   'x') OR 
  COALESCE(toda.AccountType,   'n/a') <> COALESCE(yest.AccountType,   'n/a') OR 
  COALESCE(toda.CostCenter,   0) <> COALESCE(yest.CostCenter,   0) OR 
  COALESCE(toda.TransactionLimit,   0) <> COALESCE(yest.TransactionLimit,   0) OR 
  COALESCE(toda.ClientName,   'x') <> COALESCE(yest.ClientName,   'x') OR
  COALESCE(toda.DailyCumulativeLimit,   0) <> COALESCE(yest.DailyCumulativeLimit,   0)


      SELECT
      a.run_id,
      a.AccountNumber,
      a.AccountBranch,
      a.AccountName,
      a.AccountType,
      a.CostCenter,
      b.TransactionLimit,
      b.ClientName,
      b.DailyCumulativeLimit
    FROM 
      AEI_GFXAccounts a
      LEFT JOIN AEI_GFXAccountSTP as b
      ON 
        a.feed_id = b.feed_id and 
        a.run_id = b.run_id and a.GFXAccountsID = b.GFXAccountSTPID
```

I expect it to return a view/query result that displays all accounts that have changed ONLY. With the fields that are not reliviant to populate with n/a data. But I am instead getting the error:

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>
> The conversion of the varchar value '02393224650' overflowed an int
>   column.

It does not make sense to me because the table is already supporting int numbers of that volume that are already stored in the table.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: I really doubt your table is supporting INT values of 2.3billion.   BIGINT ... sure, but not int.

Comment: How do I convert it to support big int. How do I declare/fix it?

Comment: Select try_convert(bigint,'02393224650')

Comment: The leading zero makes me wonder if the data type is not int but varchar in the source data. My guess is one of the destination tables is int when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem is that the table is design data type is actually a VarChar. The COALESCE is trying to input an int. When it is ultimately a varchar.

Comment: . . Either accept this answer or close the question, so others know that the question no longer needs an answer.

Comment: It wont allow me to accept my own answer. Should I delete this post?